# dc.js piechart legend - hide if result is 0

Tags: javascript, dc.js

Is it possible to remove/hide the legends for a piechart if the result is 0?

I have a piechart that has quite a few items in the legend, when there has been some filtering it would be great to remove the legends that are not available.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like the legend should pick up just the capped slices when it is rendered, but it doesn't have any update/redraw logic, so it won't respond to filters. You could try manually calling legend.render when the filter changes?

Comment: Sorry Gordon how would I go about that? Do you have any examples I could look at that would point me in the right direction? Many thanks.

Comment: okay, looks like i was wrong here, legends do get rerendered when the chart redraws. deleting my previous answer and writing a new one.

Answer (score 7):

Legends do render when their charts are redrawn, but the problem here is that the legend is drawn from the data, and crossfilter doesn't automatically eliminate empty groups.

It would be really great if legends were a chart type, so we could just use a fake group (a.k.a. "data transform"). But no, we need to update `.legendables()` to filter out the empty bins:

```
dc.override(pieactChart, 'legendables', function() {
    var legendables = this._legendables();
    return legendables.filter(function(l) {
        return l.data > 0;
    });
});
```

Fork of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/13t804u6/5/

Note: this only modifies the one (left) chart, you'll have to copy/paste it for each chart (or wrap it in a function) to apply it to other charts.

[I am very stubborn about not wanting such data filtering stuff inside the charts, so I'm not going to suggest this as a feature. Instead, legend should be a chart which takes its data from another chart, and there should be a way to transform that data.]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking to do this with DC.js V4 (which removed the option to override like this), I have got the following. Sharing here in case it's useful for others.

```
chartName.legendables = function () {
    return this.data().filter(x => x.value > 0).map((d, i) => {
        const legendable = { name: d.key, data: d.value, others: d.others, chart: this };
        legendable.color = this.getColor(d, i);
        return legendable;
    });
};
```