# StackBarChart Hide Legend if stack value is 0

Tags: dc.js

I have a stackedbar chart and pie chart. Initially the stackedbar chart displays the base group and 3 stacks along with a legend for all 4 items.  When I select a pie slice one of the stacks has a value of zero.  Is there a way to also remove the legend item for the stack.

Comment: I think it's just like [hiding empty legend entries for a pie chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29415900/676195) but you'll have to check all values for each stack instead of just a single value.