# multiple dimension in dataTable dc.js

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I have 5 columns `pid, cid, date, types, probability` in datatable. I am able to filter by a single column (`pid`) but I want to filter by other column values also.

https://blockbuilder.org/ninjakx/f442f5ccbf25eb853c7508194688d25d

**Line 152 (index.js):**

```
// Setup different dimensions for plots
dim.tableMaxConfidence = cf.dimension(function (d) {
  return d.pid;
});
```

I have to make it for multiple dimension filtering.

**Line 187 (index.js):**

```
.on('pretransition', function (table) {
     table.selectAll('td.dc-table-column._0')
          .on('click',function(d){
                console.log(d);
                table.filter(d.pid)
                dc.redrawAll();
           })
     table.selectAll('td.dc-table-column._1')
          .on('click',function(d){
                console.log("select:",d);
                table.filter(d.cid)
                dc.redrawAll();
           })
     table.selectAll('td.dc-table-column._2')
          .on('click',function(d){
                table.filter(d.date)
                dc.redrawAll();
           })
      table.selectAll('td.dc-table-column._4')
         .style("background-color", function(d){ 
          return color(d.probability)});
  });
```

This works only for pid since there is only pid in dimension.

So my question is it possible to filter by other column values also. If yes, then How?

Any hint will be appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a crossfilter dimension for each dimension you want to filter.

A data table normally uses its dimension just to fetch data; it doesn't have any filtering built in.

Instead of filtering through the table, you can go straight to the dimension - there isn't any difference for this chart. (You only need to use the chart's `.filter()` when it implements the selection/filtering UI.)

Of course, the dimensions must match what you're filtering:

```
 const cidDimension = cf.dimension(d => d.cid),
      dateDimension = cf.dimension(d => d.date);

 table.selectAll('td.dc-table-column._1')
      .on('click',function(d){
            console.log("select:",d);
            cidDimension.filter(d.cid)
            dc.redrawAll();
       })
 table.selectAll('td.dc-table-column._2')
      .on('click',function(d){
            dateDimension.filter(d.date)
            dc.redrawAll();
       })
```

A reset link for one of these dimensions would need to call

```
cidDimension.filter(null);
```

or

```
dateDimension.filter(null);
```

If you have a "reset all" link, you could either add those codes to it, or override the table's `filterAll`:

```
table.filterAll = () => {
    table.dimension().filter(null); 
    cidDimension.filter(null);
    dateDimension.filter(null);
};
```

Comment: Possible problem, though - since these are different dimensions they **will** filter the data table. I can't think how to avoid that.

Comment: This doesn't work. If I click on cid value. Then that value should be filtered in all the graph. it's not doing that.

Comment: I failed to understand how it will work. dimension is created and then it is used in on click functionalities.  `dateDimension.filter(d.date)` <--- how this will change the table and the pie chart. Or am I mssing something?

Comment: Crossfilter's `dimension.filter()` has nothing to do with JavaScript array filtering - this method sets the filter state of the dimension, which affects all other dimensions and their groups. I tested this with your fiddle and it works, but your `.data()` was producing NaNs - I replaced it with `.ordering()` in [this fork fork](https://blockbuilder.org/gordonwoodhull/2bb509445fa53a9d02e8a182597e55aa). If you want to remove the Others slice the right way to do that is `.othersGrouper(null)`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out mistake in piechart, I didn;t check the value that's why I was not able to make the abover solution to work I guess. fixed by using `return +d.max || 0;` also thanks for making me aware of  `.slicesCap(10)`. Using the logic given by you in https://stackoverflow.com/a/29415900/6660373 to hide the legend, I was able to fix my legend issue for pie chart. But I don't know why jsfiddle are not working. Most of the old answer's jsfiddle are not working but I guess logic will remain the same.

Comment: Yeah, thanks @Pygirl, unfortunately a lot of old fiddles pointed to github.io (despite warnings not to do this) and broke when dc.js had a version change. I fix them when I run into them. You are right, most of the code should still be valid.